# Any active wikidemocracy projects post-2019?

Tags: democracy, government, voting-systems, e-democracy

I have been reading about this form of electronic democracy called [wikidemocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-democracy#Types_of_interaction). The article on wikipedia talks about attempts to implement Wikidemocracy in 2011, but it doesn't mention any modern experiments. So I want to know, are there any major attempts by a local or nation government to implement/experiment with wikidemocracy that have been going on post-2019?

Comment: Frankly it seems like a buzzword that either has little substance, or can mean pretty much anything...

Comment: @Fixx And that's why it petered out fairly quickly.

Comment: What's the 30 word, no-buzzword, blurb on what wikidemocracy is supposed to achieve and how it is going to do that?  Failing that, what is its 30 word, no-buzzword, definition?

Answer (score 1):

"wikidemocracy" seems to be a concept entirely derived from a single internet published polemic. No actual country, state, region or subdivision has actually created a publicly editable document that would actually be the law of the land.

If one had, we would probably have had "Law-y Mac-lawface" And Rick Astley as god-emperor.

The usual objections to direct democracy apply to the wikidemocracy, with the added caveat of "digital exclusion".